# Java Swing loading image from file chooser not displaying

Tags: java, swing

This is for a class assignment. I am supposed to load a file and display it on my Swing application.

I followed the process from the notes but they were vague, I also used other stackoverflow posts, but I am not able to get this to work. When I load an image the program does not crash, but nothing displays.

-Do I have to repaint or refresh the file after the image is loaded? I tried that but it did not work. what am I doing wrong? The repaint method is commented.

```
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFileChooser;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Part1 {

    public static File selectedFile;

      public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = buildFrame();
        JButton button = new JButton("Select File");
        frame.add(button);

        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() 
        {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) 
            {
                JFileChooser fileChooser = new JFileChooser();
                int returnValue = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(null);
                if (returnValue == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) 
                {
                    selectedFile = fileChooser.getSelectedFile();
                    CardImagePanel image = new CardImagePanel(selectedFile);
                    frame.add(image);
//                  frame.repaint();
                }
            }
        });
      }

      private static JFrame buildFrame() 
      {
            JFrame frame = new JFrame();
            frame.setSize(1000,1000);
            frame.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            frame.setVisible(true);
            return frame;
      }
}

class CardImagePanel extends JPanel {
    private BufferedImage image;

    public CardImagePanel(File newImageFile)
    {
    try {
        image = ImageIO.read(newImageFile);
    } catch (IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();}
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
      super.paintComponent(g);
      g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, 500, 500, this);
    }
}
```

Comment: You could just use a JLabel and make you're life simpler. Yu should be removing what ever has already been added to the frame previously and you will need to call revalidate and repaint after you've added the new panel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As was mentioned, you need to call `frame.revalidate();` after you add the new component.

You also should call `image.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500, 500));` or similar to ensure that your image isn't tiny.

Comment: IMHO I'd be better to override getPreferredSize of the panel instead ;)